# Error while executing adb command programmatically

Tags: android, shell, adb, screenshot

I am trying to execute adb commands programmatically

Here is my code:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "screen" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

new ExecuteCommand(MainActivity.this).execute("adb shell screencap -p "
        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
        "/" + "screen" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
```

ExecuteCommand Class:

```
public class ExecuteCommand extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Context mContext=null;
    public ExecuteCommand(Context _ctx)
    {
        mContext =_ctx;
    }

    ProgressDialog progressdailog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressdailog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext,
                "Executing", "Please Wait");
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Process p;
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params[0]);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
                p.waitFor();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String response = output.toString();
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressdailog.dismiss();
        Log.e("Output", result);
    }
}
```

Problem in logs:

> 07-31 15:26:31.832  18716-18716/com.example E/Output﹕ cannot bind 'tcp:5038' * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5038 *

I am not able to take a screenshot, but if I ran the same command on command prompt then this is working fine.

But if I execute

```
new ExecuteCommand(MainActivity.this).execute("ls");
```

this works fine. Where is the problem in command?

Comment: [Why does exec() start a ADB daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112381/3290339)

Answer (score 5):

`adb shell` is used when you're executing the command in your PC trying to access the device. But when you are executing the command on device itself, you don't need `adb shell`

This will be clean:

```
new ExecuteCommand(MainActivity.this).execute("screencap -p " + f);
```

Comment: This is not working .Now output is  [ 07-31 15:38:11.494  1039:0x502 D/KeyguardViewMediator ]
    setHidden false

Comment: setHidden false probably is not the problem. This was the only output when you removed the adb shell command?

Comment: Logs from KeyguardViewMediator won't impact this. Look elsewhere. Screen record can record even on keyguard, so whether visible or not does not make a difference.

Comment: Yes , but Screenshot is not saving or may be not taken

Answer (score 5):

There have been several similar discussions on this, both on this website and [android-developers](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers), but the TL:DR is that you cannot really run all shell commands from the device. Most of them need permissions that are only granted to system apps. Using the `pm` shell commands for example needs the various package permissions, most of which are system-only. You can check the list of permissions [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).

You'll either have to root the device, or look for an alternate method of achieving what you want to.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is some issue with the permissions.

Use the new [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) apis to do it.

Refer https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture for source code.

Comment: Thanks!!! But I need to use use something from command line as I have to use other adb commands as well!!