# Why does exec() start a ADB daemon?

Tags: android, shell, adb, runtime.exec

I am building an app for some set of rooted phones I have. I was wondering if there is any way that I could uninstall a system app which comes with the phone running some code from my app.

I have tried running commands like `adb shell pm clear COM.PACKAGE.NAME` from the phone itself by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, but the output of the command is as follows:

```
cannot bind 'tcp:5038

* Daemon not running. Starting it now on port 5038*
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ADB` server starts on your host machine (`Unix`, `Windows`) and, by default, binds to port `5037`. A client (also your host machine) uses the port to send commands to a target device where the commands are executed in the system environment.

**Reference**:

1. [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) on the `Android` developer site.
2. [ADB(Android Debug Bridge): How it works?](http://www.slideshare.net/tetsu.koba/adbandroid-debug-bridge-how-it-works) by [Tetsuyuki Kobayashi](https://kobablog.wordpress.com/)

When you run an app, its code is executed in the environment. So when you call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell command")` what you actually do is trying to start another `adb` server process (on a target device now) which starts on `tcp` port `5038`, since port `5037` is busy.

To sum up: you do not need to pass `adb` parameter to the `exec()` method, it's redundant. Instead use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command")
```

Regarding uninstalling system apps programmatically, your app must get `su` first which is out of the scope of the question. Although, the following links might help you to start:

1. [ANDROID: How to gain root access in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905743/android-how-to-gain-root-access-in-an-android-application)
2. [execute shell command from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932102/execute-shell-command-from-android)