# Programmatically executing adb install command in java

Tags: java, android, command, adb

I am trying to install an android app into the device from a Java application.

Using the following command - 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb install /apps/testapp.apk");

I face the following error -
Cannot run program "adb": error=2, No such file or directory

Should I have to use ProcessBuilder to start the command execution?

Comment: I suspect this is a PATH issue; have you tried using the full path to adb, i.e. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/androidsdk/tools/adb install /apps/testapp.apk");` ?

Comment: No need to use `adb` parameter in `exec()`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104119/why-does-exec-start-a-adb-daemon) one can find an explanation why not. Use `pm install app.apk` instead. Although it's not a trivial task to execute the command programmatically. You may need to grab `su` first.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem may be

1. `adb` environment variable is not set. you can try with full path
2. path of the apk should be relative to java project CLASSPATH or the full path

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute file paths, use -r option to reinstall app if already installed:
 `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb install -r _HERE_AbsoluteFilePath_");`
If you will be waiting on an execution:

```
String[] commands = new String[3];
commands[0] = "adb";
commands[1] = "install";
commands[2] = "-r";//reinstall if already installed
commands[3] = ___HERE_AbsoluteFilePath___;
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands, null);
p1.waitFor();
```

PS: if unable to run adb in console window or terminal - use absolute file path for adb or include path to environment variable.