# Run ADB command inside app code

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I'm developing an app that will only be used inside the AVD.
My objective is automate some tasks. Sometimes, the "back button" needs to be pressed. I know that I can do it using the adb shell. However, I would like make it from my app code. I've tryed to command below, but I'm getting an "Permission denied" error.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input keyevent 4");
```

Do you have any idea how I can do it or give the necessary permissions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112381/3290339

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37091475) thread might help you sorting issues. Because as per my perspective you need root permission for that to execute commands or you can give it a try using processbuilder method.