# adb 'start server' command fails

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb, device

I connect Samsung device via USB to my laptop. When I run the command *adb start-server* from AndroidStudio/Java project, It doesn't work. 
The same command works from terminal:

**program output:**

```
I/System.out: adb start-server
I/System.out: cannot bind tcp:5038
I/System.out: daemon not running. starting it now on port 5038
I/System.out: exit: 255
```

Similar thing happends when I run *adb -d devices -l* command:

```
I/System.out: adb -d devices -l
I/System.out: cannot bind tcp:5038
I/System.out: daemon not running. starting it now on port 5038
I/System.out: exit: 1
```

**Terminal output:**

```
C:\Users...\Android\Sdk\platform-tools^adb start-server 
C:\Users...\Android\Sdk\platform-tools^
C:\Users...\Android\Sdk\platform-tools^adb -d devices -l
List of devices attached
df346805               device product:j53gxx model:SM_J500H device:j53g 
C:\Users...\Android\Sdk\platform-tools^
```

**The relevant Java command:**

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb start-server");
```

Comment: once try adb kill-server and then adb start-server.

Comment: How did you know that ADB is not started? After last update of Adnrdoid studio "adb start-server" command do not print * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 * and * daemon started successfully *

Comment: The default port usually is 5037. Have you changed it?

Comment: Try to run on different port's number. Command to run adb server on different port >$ adb -P 12345 start-server

Comment: @Dimon I don't know why, but my default port is 5038. But when I run adb -P 5037 start-server it gives me the same result: //adb start-server //cannot bind tcp:5037 //daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 //exit: 255. kill-server works, however.

Comment: I tried to run the application on different target, but got poor results: `Exception: Working Directory:null Environment:null`

Answer (score 0):

These steps may help,

1. Disconnect your phone
2. Manually kill process(adb.exe) from Task Manager if exist.
3. Apply <..sdk/platform-tools>adb kill-server in command prompt
4. Apply adb start-server

Answer (score 0):

I read in the following answer -
[Error while executing adb command programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743477/error-while-executing-adb-command-programmatically) that we have to root the device - the device has to be in superuser root mode - in order to run `adb start-server`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and solved it by running these commands

1. `which adb`

I had this return (because i had Android Studio installed) 
`/home/tiago/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb`

2. `export ADB=/home/tiago/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb`
3. `adb start-server`